# Creating an image swapping page by breaking the image into pieces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Do anyone know how these kind of website is made.
http://cloudatlas.warnerbros.com/

If there is any plugin or something that i can use.

Answer (score 1):

1. DiamondGrid.js
2. DiamondGridHTML5.js
3. DiamondGridFlash.js
4. DiamondGridMobile.js

Above JS plugin are responsible for diamond grid 'diamondGrid.css' responsible for styles, soundtrack.js responsible for BGM on that site.

Comment: Yeah, that i also saw in the source. But want to know whether these  are any plugins or not.Like whether it can be used without any licence

Comment: i think DiamondGrid.js is free. But i don,t any idea about DiamondGridHTML5 and DiamondGridFlash